# Child entity distorts when rotated - AFrame

Tags: 3d, rotation, aframe

I have a text as a child of a 3D model in an Aframe scene. At a rotation of  (0,0,0) it is fine  When I try to rotate the text , it get distorted. I don't understand why this happens. How to ensure the text maintains its shape even when it is rotated to a particular angle? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Needs elaboration. What do you mean by distorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model probably has scale applied to it. A scaled parent with a rotated child will skew. Perhaps try to cancel out the scale of the parent, or make them siblings under a container, not as a child.

```
<a-entity id="container">
  <a-entity id="model"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="text"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```